# Why is $f(x) = \sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$ = $e^{\cos(x)\ln\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but if we want to get the derivative of

$$f(x) = \sin(x)^{\cos(x)}$$

then why can we rewrite $f(x)$ as $e^{\cos(x)\ln\sin(x)}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since exponentiation and logarithm are inverse to eachother
$$x=e^{\ln(x)}$$
Applying this to the latter case and using the logarithmic rule $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ we get

$$\sin(x)^{\cos(x)}=e^{\ln(\sin(x)^{\cos(x)})}=e^{\cos(x)\ln(\sin(x))}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

That is because the exponential function is the inverse of the logarithm function.

Precisely speaking, given $\exp:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\ln:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$, we may claim that
\begin{align*}
\exp(\ln(x)) = x
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The exponent and logarithm functions are inverse of each other
$$e^{\ln f(x)}=f(x)$$
Then they use $$\ln a^b=b\ln a$$

Answer (score 1):

$\log_ax=y\implies a^y=x$

Putting back the value of $y,$

$$x=a^{\log_ax}$$

Thus, $(\sin x)^{\cos x}=e^{\ln(\sin x)^{\cos x}}=e^{\cos x\ln(\sin x)}$